# keeping encoding/appearence of greek characters when converting to data frame or saving to disk

Tags: r, text, encoding

I'm working on a text processing Rscript that is consuming greek text. The issue is I want to preserve characters when converting to dataframe and saving to disk as csv or excel file.

```
greece.letters <- c("Ήρθαν τα για να κερδίζεις κάθε μέρα!",
"Καλώς ήρθατε στην επόμενη τραπεζική εμπειρία",
"Τώρα, κάθε συναλλαγή με τις κάρτες της Τράπεζας Πειραιώς,
 μπορεί να κρύβει","Μην αφήσετε τα τέλη κυκλοφορίας να σας τρομάξουν!")

write.csv(as.data.frame(greece.letters), newgreekfile.csv)

#
# but if you take a look everything is now unicode
#

as.data.frame(greece.letters)
    <fctr>
    <U+0389><U+03C1><U+03B8>a<U+03BD> ta <U+03B3><U+03B9>a <U+03BD>a <U+03BA>e<U+03C1>d<U+03AF><U+03B6>e<U+03B9><U+03C2> <U+03BA><U+03AC><U+03B8>e µ<U+03AD><U+03C1>a!
    <U+039A>a<U+03BB><U+03CE><U+03C2> <U+03AE><U+03C1................and so on
```

Is there a way of preserving appearance or forcing to keep encoding when saving to disk?

Working on Windows 7, locale ES_es.
iconvlist() gives me almost 400 options.

```
greece.letters
[1] "Ήρθaν ta γιa νa κeρdίζeις κάθe µέρa!"                                       "Κaλώς ήρθate stην epόµeνη tρapeζική eµpeιρίa"                              
[3] "Τώρa, κάθe sυνaλλaγή µe tις κάρteς tης Τράpeζaς Πeιρaιώς, µpορeί νa κρύßeι" "Μην afήsete ta tέλη κυκλοfορίaς νa saς tροµάξουν!"
```

Original encoding is:

```
Encoding(greece.letters)
[1] "UTF-8" "UTF-8" "UTF-8" "UTF-8"
```

Comment: What OS and what locale are you using? If you print out just the column vector does it look normal? `as.data.frame(greece.letters)[,1]`? What is the original encoding of the data?

Comment: windows 7, locale ES. Printing the column vector looks fine. Original encoding [1] "UTF-8" "UTF-8" "UTF-8" "UTF-8"

Comment: I don't see from your example how `write.csv` is causing a problem. I think the `print()` code for data.frames just does the unicode escaping in order to try to make columns like up. The data in the columns should be preserved. You should only see the `<U+0389>` stuff when trying to print the entire data frame -- but that's just how it's formatted for the screen -- not what's "really" there.

Comment: The issue is that the output CSV is to be shared across organization and can't give the data as they called: "gibberish"